# Multi column sort in excel when one column is number in text format is not working

Tags: excel, sorting

I'm using two columns to sort values in excel. One is a long number(hence I have stored it in text format) and the other is numeric. I am comparing these two columns from the following two sources:

1. First is from database, the multi-column sort is working as expected.
2. Second is from a delimited file, here the issue is that when the 2nd column has same value for more than 01 row in the first column, the first column sorting is not working as expected.

Refer the snapshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adjust the sort to col2, col1 ascending as shown:
[image]